# Serialized KnowledgeBase Size (huge)

Tags: drools

(Drools 7.68.0 with dialect == MVEL)

I have a KieBase that contains 500 rules.  The serialized size of this KieBase is 5MB.  That amounts to 10KB/rule.  This seems unreasonably large.  Loading this KieBase takes up to 20 seconds to deserialize and instantiate in memory.  This limits the number of rules a given KieBase can contain.  We need to support a separate KieBase per customer (with multiple users per customer), so there are LOTS of KieBase instances of varying sizes which need to be loaded at runtime, and there is not enough memory to keep them all in memory on each server in the cluster.

Isn't there any way to (significantly) reduce the size of the KB prior to serialization?

Comment: You think that's bad? I had a KieBase with 700,000 rules. It took an hour to deploy the precompiled version ... But the performance hit was only on service startup, so we just ran multiple replicas.

Comment: Yeah, looking at the serialized KB (file on disk) I see that it contains the full text of the entire DRL that comprises the KB.  Is that necessary?  Ideally I'm looking for a way to trim down the size of the KB.  All we need is the ability to insert/update/delete facts and fire all rules.  It would be nice if there was a way to serialize just the ReteOO instance and produce a much slimmer runtime.

Comment: That's basically precompilation, like I stated. You can precompile your rules and load the precompiled form instead of the raw DRL.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I somehow missed your reply.  I believe that the serialized KB I have is compiled (post compiled).  I am calling KieHelper.build() after adding the resources, then serializing the resulting KB.  Do you know if there is something else, or different I need to do to compile the KB prior to serialization?